# how to use remote views with drawer kendo ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

i'm currently trying to use the remove views into my app but i'm going through some problems ...
my page does not get loaded and i can't figure out why ..

here is my index. html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="init/cordovaInit.js"></script>
<div data-role="view"></div>
<div data-role="drawer" id="my-drawer" style="width: 270px" data-views="    ['./views/relaySearchView.html', './views/nespressoSearchView.html', './views/dolceGustoSearchView.html']">
<ul data-role="listview" data-type="group">
  <li>Menu
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./views/relaySearchView.html">R</a></li>
      <li><a href="./views/nespressoSearchView.html">N</a></li>
      <li><a href="./views/dolceGustoSearchView.html">DG</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="layout" data-id="drawer-layout">
<header data-role="header">
  <div data-role="navbar">
  <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#my-drawer" data-icon="drawer-button" data-align="left"></a>
   <span>MR</span>
  </div>
</header>
</div>
<script>
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {skin : "flat", initial : "./views/relaySearchView.html"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here are my three views from three different html files:

```
<div data-role="view" id="drawer-relaySearch" data-layout="drawer-layout">
<p>relay</p>
</div>


<div data-role="view" id="drawer-nespressoSearch" data-layout="drawer-layout">
<p>relay</p>
</div>

<div data-role="view" id="drawer-dolceGustoSearch" data-layout="drawer-layout">
<p>relay</p>
</div>
```

hope someone can answer me, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was just the ',' missing after document in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add the attribute data-transition=none in your drawer link to make transition working properly:

Here is and example :

```
<div data-role="drawer" id="my-drawer" style="width: 270px" data-views="['drawer-home', 'view1.html', 'drawer-starred'">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-type="group">
                <li>Mailbox
                    <ul>
                        <li data-icon="inbox">
                            <a href="view1.html" data-transition="none">Remote</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-icon="star">
                            <a href="#drawer-starred" data-transition="none">Starred Items</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```